# 'I don't like fish.' 'Me, too.' Is this natural?

Tags: negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can “me, too” be used to reply to a negative statement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67167/can-me-too-be-used-to-reply-to-a-negative-statement)

'I don't like fish.'  'Me, too.'  Is this sentence natural or unnatural?
I mean not the grammatical but the communicational.

Comment: This is not natural at all.  What's wrong with all these people, that they don't like fish?  ;^)

Answer (score 4):

No. Not to me. *too* is used for responding to positive statements. *neither* would be a better choice.

```
A: 'I don't like fish.'  
B: 'Me neither.'
```

Comment: 'Me neither' is not grammatically correct in this case. It would be like replying 'Me don't like fish'.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that people 'shouldn't' use it? What about 'Me too'? Shouldn't use it either? Besides the OP is looking for a more 'natural' way of expressing the topic. To me, it means idiomatic, not grammatical. Not every idiomatic English phrase is grammatical, just so you know.

Comment: Snubian -- no it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

'Me too' is fine conversationally for communicating agreeance as in your example. It works in many situations much as one could say 'ditto!'

A more formal response to 'I don't like fish' would be:

> Neither do I.

Comment: Wouldn't the natural response be "me neither", not "me too"?

Comment: This is actually the proper answer. The question actually asks if this is natural, and yes, it is natural and common. The other answers presuppose the intent of the utterance: if one accepts that "me too" means "that describes me too," all of their objections to the utterance disapear.

Answer (score 0):

"neither do I" sounds more academic, however I've heard a lot of people saying "me neither" in the states