# "Me neither" - why oblique case?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, parts-of-speech, grammatical-case

> I don't like white wine.
>
> Me neither.

We're talking about subjects here, so naturally the pronoun should be "I". The use of "me" would only make sense to me if "neither" was a postposition. According to a dictionary it can be all kinds of things but not a preposition.

- Why are we using "me" here?
- What part of speech is neither?
- Is this sentence a shortened version of something that explains the weird grammar?

Comment: Is this sentence a shortened version of something that explains the weird grammar? "I do not like white wine either."

Comment: @Ronan ... at which point of the shortening exactly does "I" turn to "me". Your suggestion is just a different phrasing. Here's an example for a shortened sentence: "Hungry?"... is short for "Are you hungry?"

Comment: Is your answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/is-me-neither-incorrect ?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the confusing comments!